# alguien sabe por que no me da el promedio?

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace tarea2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[] num = new double[10];
            double promedio;
            int may = 0;
            int men = 0;
            int suma = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("ingrese datos");

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Elemento{i+1}");
                num [i] =int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                _ = suma + num[i];
            }
            promedio = suma / 10;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (num[i] < promedio)
                    may++;
                if (num[i] > promedio)
                    men++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nPromedio : " + promedio);
            Console.WriteLine("Mayores : "+ may);
            Console.WriteLine("Menores : "+ men);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lectura recomendada: [una captura del código/error no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/). Para evitar que te aparezca el error de que tu pregunta es netamente código, pulsa en [edit] y describe cuál es el problema que estás teniendo.

Comment: vos seguro venis de c++ y estas tratando de concatenar una cadena no? esto: Console.WriteLine("Elemento ["<<i+1<<"] "); no es valido en c#... busca sobre concatenacion de cadenas....

Comment: @gbianchi ahorita voy a investigar y si vengo de c++

Comment: Igual, por favor considera escribir en tu pregunta cual es el problema, y poner tu error como texto...

Comment: No entiendo tu edicion. Que trataste de agregar?

Comment: Yo que vos, consideraria leer como funciona c#... esto: _ = suma + num[i]; no hace nada que vos pensas que va a hacer....

Comment: logra hacer bien la concatenación @gbianchi pero ahora no me da el promedio

Comment: Y no.. lee mi otro comentario... no estas usando c# para nada...

Comment: donde crees que estas haciendo la suma?

Comment: Explica esto: `_ = suma + num[i];`

Comment: es que anteriormente me había salido un error en suma+num[i] y vi un vídeo donde lo ponían para arreglarlo y lo puse @fredyfx

Comment: Uno de los errores más grandes de los programadores es copiar y pegar código sin entender, ¡mucho cuidado eh!

Answer (score 1):

A ver si te doy algo de luz sobre tu código:

```
    //En lugar de dar de forma manual la longitud del array, yo lo pido por consola
    Console.WriteLine("Ponga el número de elementos del array");
    //recogemos en una variable el valor dado por consola
    int elementos = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    //declaramos un array de valores double y le damos como número de elementos el valor indicado por consola
    double[] num = new double[elementos];

    //Si declaras un array de valores double, no puedes luego efectuar operaciones y llevar el resultado a un valor entero, para ello deberías de hacer una conversión, por lo tanto, o bien declaras las variables de enteros y realizas dicha conversión, o bien declaras las variables como doubles
    double promedio;
    double suma = 0;

    //las variables de los contadores si pueden ser enteras
    double may = 0;
    double men = 0;
    double igu = 0;


    //pedimos los valores del array
    Console.WriteLine("ingrese los datos del array");
    //bucle con el número de iteraciones que tiene el array
    for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
    {
        //vamos enumerando los elementos al pedirlos por consola
        Console.WriteLine($"Ingrese elemento {i + 1}");
        //almacenamos el valor dado por consola en la posición actual del bucle en el array, conviertiendo el valor de texto en entero, cuando has declarado el array de valores double, así que la forma de hacerlo sería ésta y no la comentada
        num[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        //num[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //esta es la forma correcta en java de ir acumulando los valores del array en una suma
        suma += num[i];
    }
    //hayamos el promedio con la suma de los valores del array divida entre el número de valores
    promedio = suma / num.Length;

    //bucle que recorre nuevamente el array
    for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
    {
        //si el valor del array en cada iteración es mayor que el promedio
        if (num[i] > promedio)
            //aumenta en uno la variable may
            may++;
        //si es menor que el promedio
        else if (num[i] < promedio)
            //aumentamos en uno la variable men
            men++;
        //o sea, si no es ni mayor ni menor, será igual
        else
            //aumentamos en uno la vriable igu
            igu++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("El Promedio del array es de : " + promedio);
    Console.WriteLine("La suma de sus valores : " + suma);
    Console.WriteLine("Son mayores a promedio : " + may);
    Console.WriteLine("Son menores a promedio: " + men);
    Console.WriteLine("Son igual a promedio : " + igu);

    Console.ReadKey();
```